# How can I filter a nested array without mutating the original array?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to return both the inner and outer array such as the following: `[[3],[4],[5]];`

This does not work:

```
var arr = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];

arr.filter(function(el){
    return el.filter(function(inner){
        return inner >= 3;
    });
});
```

This does not work either:

```
var arr = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];

arr.map(function(el){
    return el.filter(function(inner){
        return inner >= 3;
    });
});
```

Comment: The inner array always only has one element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to get easy access to the inner array elements in the callback function:

```js
const array = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];
const filtered = array.filter(([inner]) => inner >= 3);

console.log(array); // original
console.log(filtered); // filtered
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

map() and filter() functions don't mutate the array, they return a new array with the resulting items.

In the code you show us you're not assigning the result anywhere, also, you're trying to compare an array with a number:

If you wanted to return the values inside of their wrapping arrays, you would do it like this:

```
var arr = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]];

var newArr = arr.filter(function(inner){
    return inner[0] >= 3;
});

// newArr = [[3], [4], [5]]
```

you don't need the map function if you're only filtering.